# jQuery toggle function is deprecated. What should I use instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery `.toggle()` not working after the latest version of jQuery. How should I write to make it working with the new jQuery Versions. Please help in writing the new method.

```js
jQuery('.ia_select_all').toggle( function(){
      var ia_attr_id = jQuery(this).attr( 'data-id' );
      jQuery('.' +ia_attr_id+ ' option').prop( 'selected',true );
},function(){
      var ia_attr_id = jQuery( this ).attr( 'data-id' );
      jQuery('.' +ia_attr_id+ ' option' ).prop( 'selected',false);
});
```

Comment: _not working_. Nice, how ? What is not working exactly ? Do you have any error in your console ? Have you checked the documentation to see if it's still an available method ?

Comment: @Nicolas OP's point is that method has been deprecated for years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toggle(function, function)` just alternates function to call on alternate clicks

So you should be able to replace with something like:

```
jQuery('.ia_select_all').on('click', function(){
    var ia_attr_id = jQuery(this).attr( 'data-id' );
    var $option = jQuery('.' +ia_attr_id+ ' option');
    $option.prop('selected', !$option.prop('selected'));
});
```

If you were to provide some sample html we can refine this if needed

Comment: Honestly I wonder about the value of offering transition code.. Companies pay extortionate amounts to have it done. The documentation is there, I am struggling to flag this as 'no effort shown' .. Nice blind answer though

Answer (score -1):

Here is a post from the [jquery forums](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/beginner-function-toggle-deprecated-what-to-use-instead) which suggests an alternative.

Comment: Link only answers are generally not approved, they don't answer the question and the link could die over time.